# Redirect all output of the java program to log file

Tags: java, linux, cron

I have scheduled my `jar` file by saving this line at the end of the `crontab`:

```
30 12 * * * java -jar test.jar > test.log (I have also tried test.txt)
```

Cron has started the job, also created the log file, but there is nothing in that file. Any idea why is that? I am doing `System.out.println()` in my program.

I have added write permissions to everyone for that file.

Could it happen that the scheduler crashed before the app even started? When I have checked log of the `crontab` by executing `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` it gave me fine looking output, no error indication:

```
Sep  2 12:19:01 ip-172-31-18-162 CRON[2308]: (root) CMD (java -jar /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps/apps/FullEmailReport/DJOF_FullEmail_DynamicContentReport_ScheduledPart.jar > /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps/apps/FullEmailReport/data/app.txt)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are opting to do this using the command line, instead of writing to the file in your program itself?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the *directory* where that file is? Also, are you sure there is no redirection of `System.out` inside the java program itself?

Comment: When I try to run the jar file from the shell, it says 'Error: Unable to access jarfile test.jar'. I have tried to change owner of the folder to root/ubuntu/tomcat/bitnami, I have also gave public RWE permissions to all files, but still this error occurs.

Comment: If you cannot execute the command from the command line, it's going to be difficult to program a cron job that does it ok.  This is not a cron thing then, it's something in your environment that forbids you to execute the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding 2>&1 to redirect System.err to the file too:

```
30 12 * * * java -jar test.jar > test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you, good point. However, please check my last comment under a question. It says unable to access jar file.

Comment: Don't mind the comment... I was in a different folder when I tried to execute that ;/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old question, but I thought it might be worth pointing out because no-one has mentioned it...

cron has no idea of your PATH, nor where java is. Back in my Solaris shell scripting days, we had to put full paths to everything in cron. Since I don't know where either your java installation is exactly, nor you test.jar file, I can't write the full exact command, but it might be something like:

30 12 * * * /usr/bin/java -jar /home/username/myTestStuff/test.jar > /user/username/myTestStuff/logfiles/test.log 2>&1